# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in recursive view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to simply check if I have an empty array but I get this error when I run this:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Here is how I go about doing it.

```
    <v-col>
        <v-treeview
            :active.sync="active"
            :items="items"
            activatable
            open-on-click
            transition
        >
            <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
            <div v-if=" item.data.length > 0 ">
                <v-icon v-if="!item.children">
                    mdi-account
                </v-icon>
                <div >{{ item.data.name }}</div>
            </div>
            <template v-if=" item.children.length > 0 ">
                <template v-for="(itemD, indexD) in item.children">
                    <EstructRecursive :key="indexD" name="EstructRecursive" :items="itemD" />
                </template>
            </template>
            </template>
        </v-treeview>
    </v-col>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'EstructurRecursive',
        data: () => ({
          active: [],
          avatar: null,
          open: [],
        }),
        props: {
            items: {
              type: [Array, Object],
              default: [],
            }
        },
        computed: {
          itemsC () { 
            return [
              {
                name: "list",
                children: this.items,
              },
            ]
          },
          selected () {
            if (!this.active.length) return undefined;
            
            const id = this.active[0];

            return this.items.find(item => item.id === id);
          },
        },
    }
</script>
```

struct array is:

```
items=[
        {
            "data":[{}],
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "data":[
                    {
                    "id":64,
                    "nombre":"YSVERIS"
                    }
                ],
            "children":[
                        {
                            "data":[
                                    {
                                    "id":85,
                                    "nombre":"MERCEDES"
                                    }
                                ],
                            "children":[]
                        },
                        {}
                    ]
        },
        {
            "data":[
                    {
                        "id":9,
                        "nombre":"YUDITH"
                    }
                    ],
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "data":[
                    {
                        "id":10,
                        "nombre":"YERNY DEL SOCORRO"
                    }
                    ],
        "children":[]
        },
        {
        "data":[
                {
                    "id":11,
                    "nombre":"NIDIA"
                    }
                ],
        "children":[
                    {
                        "data":[
                                {
                                "id":21,
                                "nombre":"VIVIKEY"
                                }
                            ],
                        "children":[]
                    },
                    {
                        "data":[
                                {
                                    "id":18,
                                    "nombre":"RODIMIRA "
                                }
                            ],
                        "children":[]
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
        "data":[],
        "children":[]
        },
        {
        "data":[
                {
                    "id":78,
                    "nombre":"LUCRECIA"
                }
            ],
        "children":[]
        },
        {
        "data":[
                {
                    "id":22,
                    "nombre":"DAXI XIOMARA"
                }
            ],
        "children":[]
        }
    ]
```

view dad:

```
<template>
    <v-card light>
        <v-card-title>
            Estruct
        </v-card-title>
    <v-row>
        <v-card-text>
            <EstructRecursive :items="desserts" />
        </v-card-text>
    </v-row>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>

import EstructRecursive from "./Estruct.vue";

export default {
    components: { Estruct },
    data: () => ({
        desserts: [],
    }),
    watch: {
        config() {
            this.getData();

        },
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
        let vm = this;
        axios["get"](process.env.api_url + "/estruct", {})
            .then((response) => {
            console.log("response", response.data);
            vm.desserts = response.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            });
        },
    },

    };

</script>
```

this is vuejs, and I'm building a view recursive, actually I'm showing data, but not children, so I filter in item.children.length > 0 but I'm having error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'), why this is happing???

Comment: in this line props: { itemsClientes: type: [Array, Object], default: [] }, and It comes from dad in  :items="desserts"

Comment: I solved it myself, this filtre work for me       <div v-if="item.data != null " > and
        <template v-if="Object.keys(item.data).length > 0">,